# WPF add element to UI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Super basic question, I just wanna add a label to my window. I've looked through similar questions but found no answer.

I have my XAML code:

```xml
<Window [some preset values...]
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="childGrid"></Grid>
</Window>
```

And my C# code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Label testLabel = new Label();
            testLabel.Content = "TEST";
            this.AddChild(testLabel);
        }
    }
```

Nothing shows up on the window, no error thrown. What c# code do I need to fix this?

Comment: removing `InitializeComponent();` from constructor was bad idea

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that a wpf Label is not a direct equivalent to web or winforms label. A TextBlock is probably what you really want. ( And a book.) A label is a content control. When you set content to a string it generates a textblock as content and sets it's text property to that string. Labels also do some other things. Read up on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave the `InitializeComponent()` default call in the constructor for a start.

Then, a `Window` can only have one child, so you should set its `Content` to replace the `Grid` you already have.

```cs
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Label testLabel = new Label();
    testLabel.Content = "TEST";
    this.Content = testLabel;
}
```

Finally, this is not the way things have been designed to work in WPF, this is not the same principles as in Windows Forms. You should define your `Label` in XAML if you want it in your `MainWindow` from the start, like this:

```xml
<Window>
    <Label Content="Test"></Label>
</Window>
```

If you want both a `Grid` and a `Label` inside, so be it but you probably should read more introduction about XAML and WPF anyway if you wan't to get it right from the start:

```xml
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Name="childGrid">
            <Label Content="Test"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks :]. I've programmed mostly in windows forms so far, and I propably removed the call on accident and forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the code-behind, you can take advantage of wpf's XAML:

```
<Window [some preset values...]
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="childGrid">
        <Label Content="Test"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(not tested, wrote it in a hurry)

Check out this nice guide I used to learn how to use WPF well enough for a simple desktop app:
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-label-control/